# Interleaving processes on two threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have a library that I can use to access some tabular data. This library is the only way I have of accessing the data. The method I am using takes a query string and a callback that is called for each result row.

Currently, the callback loads each row into a List and then returns the List. I would like to use an iterator pattern, but the only access I have to the data is via this callback method.

**Is there a way I can run the query/callback on a second thread and interleave that code with iterator code?** Psudocode:

```
IEnumerable<Row> QueryData(string queryString)
{
    var callerLock = create new sync lock;
    var callbackLock = create new sync lock;
    var rows = create new stack of rows with capacity 1;
    var qthread = create new thread with QueryCallback(queryString, callerLock, callbackLock, rows);

    start qthread;
    while (qthread is running)
    {
        signal callbackLock;
        wait for callerLock;

        if stack is empty
            break;

        var row = pop from rows;
        yield return row;
    }
}

void QueryCallback(string queryString, lock callerLock, lock callbackLock, Stack<Row> rows)
{
    DoQueryWithCallback(queryString, row =>
    {
        wait for callbackLock;
        push row to rows;
        signal callerLock;
    });

    signal callerLock;
}
```

I have tried to implement this with most of the locks available in the .NET Framework, but none of them work. I recall trying Semaphore, SemaphoreSlim, AutoResetEvent, ManualResetEvent, and Mutex.

P.S.: DoQueryWithCallback is from the library. It is a native library (ILSpy/Reflector/etc can't decompile it). I imagine the function looks something like this:

```
long DoQueryWithCallback(string queryString, Callback rowCallback)
{
    do some setup;

    Row row;
    while (next(out row))
            rowCallback(row);

    do some teardown;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to emulate a lazily evaluated iterator.

Comment: What do you expect to gain by doiing that? If the underlying data source doesn't support it then what do you get apart from the sizable overhead of multiple threads and locking?

Comment: @xxbbcc: Maybe the readability of processing each item in a loop instead of via a callback, yet not requiring the entire set to be loaded at once? Not that I don't agree with you about the overhead...

Comment: @DarkFalcon You may be right but at the end of the day that callback code will still be around somewhere if that's the only way to get the data. Anything else on top of it is overhead of some kind. I'm not sure I'd bother - the gains are very questionable for a considerable level of complexity. At the end, all the waits will slow doiwn the process quite a bit.

Comment: Initially I didn't want to wait for the entire result set before seeing the first result. And also what DarkFalcon said. In the end, I agree with xxbbcc about the overhead, but I spend too long trying and failing to find a solution to give up. I will never use the code, but I want to know how to do this on principle. It seems like exactly what locks are designed for, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding the pseudocode correctly, you want to trigger off the fetch operation on a background thread and yield the results with an iterator as they come in, rather than waiting for the entire fetch operation to complete before returning. A couple of things that I would change:

- If you want to maintain the order in which the rows are fetched, use a queue instead of a stack
- The signalling/blocking only needs to go one way - the thread yield returning rows needs to wait for the fetching thread to add items to the queue. There is no need to block the fetching thread

Here is a quick example using a `Task`, `ConcurrentQueue` and `AutoResetEvent`:

```
public IEnumerable<Row> GetRows(string query)
{
    using (var resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    {
        var rows = new ConcurrentQueue<Row>();

        var queryTask = Task.Run(() => DoQueryWithCallback(query, r =>
        {
            rows.Enqueue(r);
            resetEvent.Set();
        }));
        queryTask.ContinueWith(t => resetEvent.Set()); // This ensures that queryTask.IsCompleted will be true in the while loop below

        while (resetEvent.WaitOne() && !queryTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            Row row;
            while (rows.TryDequeue(out row))
                yield return row;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

There is actually a better way using [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public IEnumerable<Row> GetRows(string query)
{
    using (var rows = new BlockingCollection<Row>())
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            DoQueryWithCallback(query, r => rows.Add(r));
            rows.CompleteAdding();
        });

        while (!rows.IsCompleted)
            yield return rows.Take();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it is probably the best way to get the results immediately without waiting for the entire fetch to finish. But I still would like to know how to interleave code on two different threads. I tried using AutoResetEvents to achieve this, but the callback seemed to be entering the lock multiple times with only one call to Set.